# why angular js not loads instantly, it takes time to load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

This is the demo is used to build my project:

https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/demo/

I changed a lot of menus but the page heading and the data stayed the same. I face the same problem as in the demo. The browser does not render the page instantly but it takes some time in the beginning before the elements content is shown.

Comment: What is the exact problem you want us to answer, is it that while page is loading you can see {{}} in HTML?

Comment: Check the network tab of the browsers development tools. Everything is loaded async by Ajax requests. This takes some time in the beginning. Please rephrase your question and be more specific what is actually loading slowly (with code).

Comment: ya it shows {{obj.title}} like then after some time the data came in obj.title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ngCloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) to prevent that. Put `ng-cloak` on your body tag and follow the documentation.

> When this css rule is loaded by the browser, all html elements (including their children) that are tagged with the ngCloak directive are hidden. When Angular encounters this directive during the compilation of the template it deletes the ngCloak element attribute, making the compiled element visible.
>
> For the best result, the angular.js script must be loaded in the head section of the html document; alternatively, the css rule above must be included in the external stylesheet of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear! But from what u r facing seems, your one/more service call(s) taking time to fetch data intially which might be making your application slow. Go to network in dev tools and check which service is taking lots of time!